# CLLocationmanager: Save battery

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

My new "app in progress" uses an instance of CLLocationManager for several purposes. To make the app as battery-friendly as possible, the location services should be activated only if needed, and deactivated immediately when the data refresh is done. For my purpose it's perfectly enough to fetch the location data only once in 10 seconds. (Haven't yet decided the exact interval length).

My question is, which is the most battery-efficient method of "turning off the Location services"? Is it sufficient to just use the "stopUpdatingLocation" method and keep the CLLocationManager himself in memory, or am I required to release the entire instance, and allocate a new one before the next refresh?

Comment: Every ten seconds seems like a lot. Users won't be traveling great distances in that little time unless it's a GPS app.

Comment: I consider adding a user preference, where the user can choose whether the positioning should be running in full-power mode or in "flower power mode". What the app could be used for, is not 100% clear at the moment, I hope there will be any use for it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the other answers that `stopUpdatingLocation` in combination with the `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` is the way to go. Note that when the desired accuracy is in the scope of kilometres, the location manager might not even have to fire up the GPS.

Similarly, depending on what you use it for, have a look at region monitoring and significant location updates since those are more battery friendly.

Related: [Location Awareness Programming Guide - Tips for Conserving Battery Power](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)

Comment: And I just want to add that even though you request a desired accuracy of 10 meters or even 100 meters, you may never get it if the user is inside a large building with no GPS reception and WiFi turned off (I have found that a lot of people turn off WiFi when they're at work for example). If this is the case, you won't get updates every 10 seconds either, since the delegate method that returns a new location only fires when the user moves to another cell-tower (which won't be the case if they're inside with no Wifi on + GPS)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Calling `stopUpdatingLocation` is enough.

Better way is to set good values for `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy`. 10secs is not enough time to warm up the gps.

[CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

Setting appropriate `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` are probably the two factors that have the most impact on you battery life.

#### However

To really know what is the most battery-friendly you should use Instruments and measure the battery drain on the device. There is a built-in tool for that.