# iPhone: Listening to GPS regularly and battery drain

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to iPhone development and I have an idea for an app that requires that I record the GPS position at least every 5 minute.

Is this possible without draining the battery completely?

TIA
Soeren

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10470036/1463604

Answer (score 2):

You can try using timer and turning on/off gps.

So turn on GPS,record coordinates,start timer,turn off GPS and after some interval[around 2-3 mins] turn on GPS,record location and turn off GPS...repeat...

Comment: Thanks, is it realisttic to do this every 5 minute without draining the battery? I need to do it all the time - also when the program is in the background.

Comment: You can run this every 3 minute as after 3minute app will stop working without any kind of background service on.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Before every 3 mins interval turn on and off GPS so your app keeps running in background mode.

Comment: And if I do that it will not drain the battery?

Comment: It will drain some amount of battery but very less compared to continuous drainage